# mapping between two text file contain arabic characters c#

Tags: c#

I have text file contains data like as:

```
ID 1 Name Mary Mark 89
ID 2 Name Mai   Mark 67
```

and I have another text file contains data :

```
ID  Mobile
1   0993209320
2   0943043094
```

I want to create excel file which contains only two columns:

```
Mobile                      Message
0993209320            ID 1 Name Mary Mark 89
0943043094            ID 2 Name Mai   Mark 67
```

to do this,I tried the following code, it works fine, and the required excel file was created, but when I change the data contained in both text file to Arabic, the code created excel file, but Empty, what should I do to modify the code to make it able to deal with arabic character??
this is the code:

```
    DataTable dtMapping = new DataTable();
    ArrayList lstMapping = new ArrayList();
    dtMapping.Columns.Add("Mobile"); dtMapping.Columns.Add("Message");
    string[] readFile1 = File.ReadAllLines(Location of 1st file);
    string[] readFile2 = File.ReadAllLines(Location of 2nd file);


         for (int i = 0; i < readFile1.Length; i++)
            {
                string fileData = readFile1[i].ToString();
                int find_Id_Index = fileData.IndexOf("ID ");
                if (find_Id_Index != -1)
                {
                    int find_Name_Index = fileData.IndexOf("Name ", find_Id_Index);
                   string id = fileData.Substring(find_Id_Index+3,find_Name_Index-(find_Id_Index+3) ).Trim();
                    lstMapping.Add("ID " + id);
                    lstMapping.Add(fileData.Substring(find_Name_Index, fileData.Length - (find_Name_Index)).Trim());
                }
            }


            for (int i = 1; i < readFile2.Length; i++)
            {
                int find_Space_Index = readFile2[i].IndexOf(" ");
                if (find_Space_Index != -1)
                {
                    string file2id = readFile2[i].Substring(0, find_Space_Index).Trim();
                    string mobileno = readFile2[i].Substring(find_Space_Index, readFile2[2].Length - (find_Space_Index - file2id.Length+1)).Trim();
                    int find_Id = lstMapping.IndexOf("ID " + file2id);
                    if (find_Id != -1)
                    {
                        dtMapping.Rows.Add(mobileno, "ID " + file2id + " " + lstMapping[find_Id + 1]);
                    }
                }
            }


            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
            for (int i = 0; i < dtMapping.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = dtMapping.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dtMapping.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dtMapping.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = dtMapping.Rows[i][j];
                }
            }
            excelApp.Visible = true;
```

Comment: You said nothing about *how* you created the text file.  Ensure that it is saved in UTF-8 encoding, that's the encoding you use to read the text file.

Comment: the text file is already existed , i will try to use the encoding utf-8

Comment: what is the default locale of your machine?  I think this maybe a localization problem since the file is in Arabic. You may need to utilize the CultureInfo class